# Java Script Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    alert('helllo');
    $('button.savebtn').click(function() {
        alert('testin');
        var Row1 = $(this).closest('tr').find("#mi").text();
        alert(Row1);
        var Row2 = $(this).closest('tr').find("#mn").text();
        var dataString = "Id=" + Row1 + "&Name=" + Row2;
        alert(dataString);
    });
</script>
```

I got the the following error from above code, is anyone able give me the reason why the error occurs??

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>           at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:875:140)
>           at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:808:34)
>           at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:664:21)

Comment: You don't need `<script>` when adding JS in separate file.

Comment: Yup within any file with a `.js` extension you **just** write *javascript*, HTML is allowed in there but only as a string to be appended to other elements.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: Anything is allowed inside strings. Saying "HTML is allowed" makes it look like there is somwthing special about it.

Comment: I have create the different file but still the error still there:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src = "test.js"> </script>

Comment: @dao: Seeems like you still have HTML in a JavaScript file. That's invalid. Don't do that.

Comment: @felix: which one is html? if i inspect the element inside the script it run properly. When I inspect together with the script those error appears, and the webpage not function properly.

Comment: `<script></script>` is an *HTML element*, just like `<div>` or `<span>`. It cannot appear inside a JavaScript script. To learn more about HTML, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction .

Comment: it was in html file.. I put the both script in my html page: 
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>; 
<script src = "test.js"> </script>
but the error appears on this java script : <script src = "test.js"> </script>
not sure which part did I missed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your JS in a separate file you don't need to add `<script>` and `</script>`.

Comment: I have created the different file, but the error still appears on the same java scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here list of the full html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<TITLE>LIST OF GATE</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H2>Data</H2>

<TABLE BORDER=1>
<TR>
<TH>ID</TH><TH>NAME</TH><TH>ACTION</TH>
<TR>
<TD id = "mi">1</TD>
<TD id = "mn" contenteditable="true">a</TD>
<TD> <button class= savebtn>Save</button> </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD id = "mi">2</TD>
<TD id = "mn" contenteditable="true">b</TD>
<TD> <button class= savebtn>Save</button> </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD id = "mi">3</TD>
<TD id = "mn" contenteditable="true">c</TD>
<TD> <button class= savebtn>Save</button> </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY></HTML>
```